# How to implement a linkedlist using Typescript in a functional component in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, data-structures, linked-list, react-functional-component

I'm currently learning data structures on my own. Most websites provide an implementation using classes and I'm unable to find an implementation using functions for functional components.

I want to learn how to implement a linkedlist using Typescript in a functional component in React.

Comment: A linked list is a data structure only. A functional component relates to UI concerns.  If you want to learn *data structures*, you shouldn't make that dependent on UI concerns.

Comment: What does it even mean for a React component to *be* a data structure? I don't believe you'd be doing a linked list, or a hashmap, or a heap, or anything else even if it was a class component.

Comment: As for how to make a "functional linked list" - it's easy: `interface Node<T> { value: T, next: Node<T> | null }`. Now you need to define functions that deal with this, like an `function append<T>(Node<T>, value: T): Node<T>`. Which will have the same logic you'd have if you had a class but it's not a method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.